# How to reset global Basic Authentication header in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, http-headers

In my angular app the global `$http` headers are defined for every request, like this:

```
function useBasicAuth(username, hash) {
    var encoded = btoa(username + ':' + hash);
    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic ' + encoded;
}
```

How to disable sending this information, when for example the user logs out, and the authentication is no longer required?

Answer (score 1):

What I found as a working solution was to redeclare the `$http.defaults.headers.common` Object so it won't contain the headers.

Example:

```
function useBasicAuth(username, hash) {
    var encoded = btoa(username + ':' + hash);
    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic ' + encoded;
}
```

This, however won't delete the cached credentials from the browser. To overcome this, I've made a simple - and **not** asynch call to generate a bad request on purpose.

This is the function for this in my accountServices factory:

```
function checkAuth(username, hash) {
    var encoded = btoa(username + ':' + hash);
    var result = false;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function (request) {
            request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Basic ' + encoded);
        },
        url: "user/current",
        statusCode: {
            401: function () {
                result = false;
            },
            200: function (response) {
                result = response;
            }
        },
        async: false
    });

    return result;
}
```

To log the user out, I call this function:

```
function useBasicWithoutAuth() {
    accountServices.checkAuth('logout','logout');
    $http.defaults.headers.common = {Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"};

}
```

So what this does, is it first sends a request to a protected URL, with a fake and non-existant user, so it's basically the same, as if the prompt would appear to you, and you'd click cancel.

After this has been done, there's no cached data in the browser, we can simply remove the headers from Angular, so it won't send any `Authorization` information, where it's not needed.